# Regular Expression Match Doesn't Start With, Contain, Or End With Space And Not Empty String

Tags: c#, regex, spaces, string

I am writing a C# program that needs to validate an input string to make sure that it doesn't start with a space, doesn't contain a space, and doesn't end with a space.

I am currently using the following regular expression:

```
^[\S]*$
```

This works great on all strings except if the string is empty:

```
"HELLO" (Match)
"H" (Match)
"HE LLO" (No Match)
" HELLO" (No Match)
"HELLO " (No Match)
"" (Match)
```

As you can see the empty string "" returns a match which is not what I want.

How do I modify my regular expression to also make sure the string is not empty?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just replace the zero-or-more quantifier (`*`) with a one-or-more quantifier (`+`). Also, there's no need to wrap the `\S` in a character class. Try this:

```
^\S+$
```

**Further Reading:**

- [Quantifiers in Regular Expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3206d374.aspx)

Comment: Wow that was easy enough! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit easier just to test on the presence of

```
 \s
```

anywhere ...

Comment: You would still have to check the length of the string. An empty string doesn't contain a `\s` anywhere.